# Subsonic 3.0 setup problems

Tags: subsonic3

I am trying to re-create the setup project as shown in the video of http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_3.0

i am using visual c# 2008 express edition and following all the steps but something is wrong.

the settings.ttinclude is as follows:

```
const string Namespace = "WSC";
const string ConnectionStringName = "WSC";

//This is the name of your database and is used in naming
//the repository. By default we set it to the connection string name
const string DatabaseName = "WSC";

//this is a list of tables you don't want generated
string[] ExcludeTables = new string[]{
"sysdiagrams",
"BuildVersion",
};
```

.. i am adding the subsonic.core.dll referense and creating the app.config with the following settings:

I am also copying the ActveDirectory Folder found in the t4 templates directory to the solution. .cs files are supposed to be generated here but they are not.

Can anyone help pls.

Regards,

Adrian

Answer (score 2):

It's not that SubSonic doesn't work with Express per se...it's that Express doesn't support T4 templates, which are used by SubSonic to generate your classes.

Answer (score 1):

apparently subsonic 3.0 does not work with the express version of visual studio 2008. I tried it with a standard version of VS 2008 and everything worked perfectly.

Can anyone confirm my claim please.

Keep up the good work

Adrian